# iPhone not connecting to 3G after losing wifi connection

Tags: network, wifi, iphone, cellular-data

Everytime I am connected to wifi, then lose the connection (e.g. by leaving the house), the 3G on my iphone 4s refuses to work. I have to turn my phone off and on in order to get 3G again, and then I lose the 3G again next time I connect to the wifi.

I can work around the problem so theres no point getting my phone repaired or doing anything drastic, I just wanted to know if any of you knew what is causing this and if there is an easy way to fix it.

Comment: do you use the 3G network provider Internet/wifi as well

Comment: The phone should always have a 3G connection whether or not the WiFi is on or off or connected to a base station or not. Are you able to determine if 3G / data was working before WiFi drops or just assuming it's working up to that point?

Comment: @buscar Yeh it's the same wifi provider as it is 3G provider, but this happens even when I connect to wifi's that aren't the same provider

Comment: @bmike I didn't realise the iphone was using up my mobile data even when connected to wifi, I have no need of 3G when I'm connected to wifi so I was just assuming it was working up until I was connected to the wifi.

Comment: The OS is smart enough to only send very small notifications, but it does keep both connections alive. The majority of OS traffic and all app traffic goes over WiFi when that is connected and viable.

Comment: @man-qa: Which iOS version are you running? I have experienced many types of problems similar to the ones you describe on my iPhone 5 iOS6. Those were gone once I upgraded to iOS7.

Comment: @gruber Just checked which iOS version I'm on, its 7.1.1 :/

Comment: It isn't a problem with his phone specifically it's a problem with all iphones. Mine does it too. People have been griping about this for ages.

Answer (score 3):

Is it Jailbroken?
If not, I'd suggest going to see Apple Genius and see whether its anything hardware wise.

Comment: Its not jailbroken, I think your probably right about it being hardware related as it is 2-3 years old.

Comment: Its fine :) I'm sure they're figure it out

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the cellular data network settings. This problem once happened to me; I was on O2 and once I changed the settings over to what the network provider told me to it worked. Also if you call your network provider they can change your settings remotely.